# Opsworks - Rails application in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have the following folder structure in my git repository:

```
/
/MyApp
/MyApp/app
/MyApp/bin
/MyApp/...
/MobileClient
```

**MyApp** is the Rails application (directory) which I'm trying to deploy using AWS OpsWorks. The **MobileClient** directory is just as it sounds.

I'm deploying via git (also, set the *Document Root* setting to MyApp/public) however the deployment fails and I'm also seeing on the machine that the generated config, log and public directories are on the root level instead of being in the subdirectory.

Is there a simple way of using a git deployment for a Rails app which resides in a subdirectory?

Comment: The deployment fails with what messages?

Comment: Deployment fails when I try to migrate for example, OpsWorks assumes the top directory is a Rails application when it's actually in a subdirectory.